# Can an interface have multiple classes in C# and can a class have multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can an interface have multiple classes in C#?

Can a class have multiple interfaces?

Comment: Interfaces can't inherit from a class and from multiple much less

Comment: i guess you can simply find this if you had tried searching google for it. Also have a look at [How to ask questions on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx): _"... a class or struct can implement multiple interfaces, but a class can inherit only a single class, abstract or not. Therefore, by using interfaces, you can include behavior from multiple sources in a class."_

Comment: According to your first question, presuming that you want to know if an interface _can be implemented by multiple other interfaces or classes_. Yes, of course. Otherwise an interface would be useless if it could be implemented only by a single other interface/class.

Answer (score 1):

yes and yes.

many classes can implement the same interface and a class can implement many different interfaces

Edit: Maybe I misunderstood your first question. But an Interface can only inherit from another interface. And a class can only inherit from 1 other class (abstract class) or multiple interfaces

Comment: "Can an interface have multiple classes" sounds as if OP wants to know if interfaces can inherit from classes

Comment: hmm jep, maybe I misunderstood that